# Table of content including title in metadata

Tags: table-of-contents, titles, article, metadata

I'm currently creating a journal with several articles using a template. My problem is that I'm not able to include the title of the article in the TOC, just the sections. Let me show you the problem:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
% ------
% Fonts and typesetting settings
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\linespread{1.05} % Palatino needs more space between lines
\usepackage{microtype}

% ------
% Page layout
\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1,top=32mm,columnsep=20pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[font=it]{caption}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{multicol}

% ------
% Lettrines
\usepackage{lettrine}

%-----------
%Paquete Español
%-----------
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

% ------
% Abstract
\usepackage{abstract}
\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalfont\small\itshape}

% ------
% Titling (section/subsection)
\usepackage{titlesec}
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\large\scshape\centering}{\thesection.}{1em}{}

% ------
% Header/footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[C]{E-Zine Miura 42  $\bullet$ Noviembre 2014 $\bullet$ Vol. I, Nº. 1}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}
```

% ------
      Here's the title that I want to include in the TOC

```
   % ------
   % Maketitle metadata <===> This
   \title{\vspace{-15mm}% 
        \fontsize{24pt}{10pt}\selectfont
        \textbf{The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy }
    }   
    \author{%
    \large
    \textsc{42}\thanks{Template by \href{http://www.howtotex.com}{UNIVERSE}} \\[2mm]
        \normalsize 42 \\
        \normalsize \href{mailto:frits@howtoTeX.com}{42.com (
        \vspace{-5mm}
        }
        \date{}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% ---------------
%%% BEGIN DOCUMENT
%%% ---------------

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\begin{abstract}
\noindent La Guía del autoestopista galáctico o Guía del viajero intergaláctico        

El título del libro fue inspirado en una Guía verdadera que Adams vio, la cual era 
\end{abstract}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lettrine[nindent=0em,lines=3]{A} rthur Dent podría calificarse en todo           sentido como una persona normal. Un sujeto que vive en un pacífico pueblito a las afueras de Londres.

\section{Personajes: Ejemplo de sección}
Maecenas sed ultricies felis. Sed imperdiet dictum arcu a egestas. 
\begin{compactitem}
\item Arthur Dent, el protagonista de esta historia, es un hombre normal que     

\section{Otro ejemplo}

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the main title (*The Hitchhiker’s guide to the galaxy*) doesn't appear in the TOC.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `title` and `author` commands look horrible to me. They should not include Layout instructions, just the plain text. Use a package like `titling` if you want to alter the appearance of the title header.
ftp://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titling/titling.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add the entry manually by writing this line next to command `\maketitle`.

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\LARGE The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy}
```

Literal meaning of this line is:

add a line in the index `TableOfContents`, using the same style of the `section`,
and containing `\LARGE The Hitchhiker's...`.

Anyway beware that command `\maketitle` works only once in `article`. To do a journal I think you sould use a dedicated `documentclass` instead of `article`. I think there are many around.

Comment: In the same way. Put this line of code where the related title lies.

Comment: So, it's better to use a documentclass for a journal instead of the article. Could you recommend a good template for this?

Comment: it's no template, it's a program :)
anyway I would use something like this:
http://www.guit.sssup.it/downloads/arstexnica.zip, with his example http://www.guit.sssup.it/download/atsample.tex